# Stuck on rendering lights after binding FBO using deffered rendering using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, framebuffer, deferred-rendering

First of all I am sorry for this long post after trying to make this work the whole day.

I have many questions about this especially because I use inheritance in C++ to build lights.

I use directional light as my core model for light since i can give the light direction and it will calculate the light, then on top of it I build point light where i just calculate the vector from light to fragment position, and finally for spot light I use point light with the addition of cut off angle to create spot lights (just ignore whatever is outside the cone). I have tested lights and they work fine with forward rendering but now I would like to change my light model to PBR (basically just change how I calculate light in directional light) and move to differed rendering.

Today i started working on deferred rendering and I can get the position, texture, normal and depth buffers, however i have a problem when trying to render lights.

That was the first problem, the second, since each type of light has it own shader and i build them using polymorphism. My second question is I can loop through each light in C++ and call each light to be renderer or there is another way that i can solve this in shaders.
Prototypes of lights are
EDIT: I fixed a small issue where iw as transforming the render quat with VP projection but still i can not draw anything and i have no idea if FB are working correctlly now. Nvidia opengl debugger is just crashing.

```
 Light(glm::vec3& color, float intensity, float ambient, ShaderProgram& lightShader);
 DirectionalLight(glm::vec3& color = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), glm::vec3& position = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), float intensity = 1.0f, float ambient = 0.0f, ShaderProgram& lightShader = ShaderProgram("Directional Light"));
    PointLight(glm::vec3& color = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), glm::vec3& position = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), float intensity = 1.0f, float ambient = 0.0f, LightAttenuation& lightAttenuation = LightAttenuation(), ShaderProgram& lightShader = ShaderProgram("Point Light"));
 SpotLight(glm::vec3& color = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), glm::vec3& position = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
```

My render path looks like this.

```
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

        defferedShader_.startProgram();
        defferedShader_.setUniformMat4("VP", camera.getVP());


        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, deferredFbo);

        //the scene is small and does not need culling.
        for (auto* mesh : world.getMeshes()) {

            //mesh->draw(light->getLightShader());
            //mesh->draw(activeLight_->getLightShader());
            mesh->draw(defferedShader_);

            drawCallCounter += mesh->getMeshObjectSize();
        }

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        defferedShader_.stopProgram();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, positionFbo);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, normalFbo);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, albedoFbo);

               //This is where i got stuck, I would like to make directional light work then test other lights then test the whole program with more than one light
        //for (auto* light : world.getLights()) {
        //  //glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        //  //glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
            glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            activeLight_->getLightShader().startProgram();

            activeLight_->getLightShader().setUniformMat4("VP", camera.getVP());
            activeLight_->getLightShader().setUniformVec3("eyePosition", camera.getCameraPosition());

            //activeLight_->getLightShader();
            RenderQuad();

            activeLight_->getLightShader().stopProgram();

  //}
```

The shader code that i started building is (PS i removed the shadows for now)
Vertex Shader

```
    #version 410 core

#include "../Global/GlobalShader.inc"
#include "../Global/GlobalMesh.inc"

out vec3 Position;
out vec2 TexCoord;
//out vec4 ShadowCoord;

//uniform mat4 ShadowMatrix;

void main() {

    Position = position;
    TexCoord = texCoord;

    //ShadowCoord = ShadowMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = VP * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader
One thing that is bothering me is i can not set the uniform values for gPosition, gPosition and gAlbedoSpec even if I use them, and no matter what i change in the shader the output will be the same.

```
        #version 410 core

    #include "../Global/GlobalShader.inc"
    #include "../Global/GlobalMesh.inc"
    #include "../Global/GlobalLight.inc"
    //#include "../Global/ShadowSampling.inc"

    in vec3 Position;
    in vec2 TexCoord;
    //in vec4 ShadowCoord;

    uniform sampler2D gPosition;
    uniform sampler2D gNormal;
    uniform sampler2D gAlbedoSpec;

    float specularStrength = 32.0f; // to be impelemented

    out vec4 gl_FragColor;
    void main() {

        //vec4 lightning = vec4(0.0f);
        ////vec4 shadowMapping = vec4(0.0f);
        //
        vec3 FragPos = texture(gPosition, TexCoord).rgb;
        vec3 Normal = texture(gNormal, TexCoord).rgb;
        vec3 Diffuse = texture(gAlbedoSpec, TexCoord).rgb;
        float Specular = texture(gAlbedoSpec, TexCoord).a;

        //vec3 Diffuse = texture(gAlbedoSpec, TexCoord).rgb;
        //lightning = calculateDirectionalLight(directionalLight.light, directionalLight.position, Normal, Position, specularStrength, eyePosition, material, TexCoord);
        //gl_fragColor = vec3(Position, 1.0);
        //shadowMapping = calculateShadow(shadowMap, ShadowCoord, directionalLight.light.ambient);
        //gl_FragColor = vec4(Diffuse, 1.0);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0); //vec4(Diffuse, 1.0);// lightning;//g * shadowMapping;

        //gl_FragColor = lightning;// * shadowMapping;
    }

in case you want to see global light 

    struct Light
{
    vec3 color;
    float intensity;
    float ambient;
};

struct DirectionalLight
{
    Light light;
    vec3 position;
};

struct Attenuation
{
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
};

struct PointLight
{
    Light light;
    Attenuation atten;
    vec3 position;
    float range;
};

struct SpotLight
{
    PointLight pointLight;
    //vec3 lookAt;
    vec3 direction;
    float cutOff;
};

vec3 GAMMA = vec3(1.0/2.2);

vec4 calculateDirectionalLight(Light light, vec3 direction, vec3 normal, vec3 worldPosition, float specularIntensity, vec3 eyePosition, Material material, vec2 texCoord)
{
        vec3 diffuseFactor = ( light.color * material.diffuse * vec3(texture(material.texture.diffuse, texCoord.st)) )
                                                 * (light.intensity * clamp(dot(normal, direction), 0.0, 1.0) ) ;

        vec3 viewDir = normalize(eyePosition - worldPosition);
        vec3 reflectDir = normalize(reflect(-direction, normal));

        float specularFactor = pow(clamp(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0, 1.0), specularIntensity);
        vec3 specularColor = ( light.color * material.specular * vec3(texture(material.texture.specular, texCoord.st)) ) * (specularFactor * material.shininess);

        return vec4(pow((diffuseFactor + specularColor + light.ambient + material.ambient), GAMMA), 1.0);
}

vec4 calculatePointLight(PointLight pointLight, vec3 normal, vec3 worldPosition, float specularIntensity, vec3 eyePosition, Material material, vec2 texCoord)
{
        // DO NOT NORMALIZE lightDirection, WE NEED IT TO CALCULATE THE DISTANCE TO COMPARE RANGE OF LIGHT
        vec3 lightDirection = pointLight.position - worldPosition;
        float distanceToPoint = length(lightDirection);

        // I dont like conditionals in shader, but since this is fragment based lighting i believe
        // this will speed-up things insetead of calculating the light
        if(distanceToPoint > pointLight.range)
                return vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);

        vec4 light = calculateDirectionalLight(pointLight.light, lightDirection, normal, worldPosition,  specularIntensity, eyePosition, material, texCoord);

        // light attenuateion explained https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Constant-Linear-Quadratic_Falloff
        // http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Light+Attenuation+Shortcut
        float attenuation = max(pointLight.atten.constant
                                + pointLight.atten.linear * distanceToPoint
                                + pointLight.atten.quadratic * distanceToPoint * distanceToPoint,
                                1.0);

    return light / attenuation;
}

vec4 calculateSpotLight(SpotLight spotLight, vec3 normal, vec3 worldPosition, float specularIntensity, vec3 eyePosition, Material material, vec2 texCoord) 
{
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(spotLight.pointLight.position - worldPosition);
    float spotFactor = dot(lightDirection, spotLight.direction);

    vec4 light = vec4(0.0f);
    if(spotFactor > spotLight.cutOff)
    {
        light = calculatePointLight(spotLight.pointLight, normal, worldPosition, specularIntensity, eyePosition, material, texCoord) * (1.0 - (1.0 - spotFactor)/(1.0 - spotLight.cutOff));
    }

    return light;
}
```

Global mesh

```
   struct Texture {
    sampler2D diffuse;
    sampler2D specular;
    sampler2D normal;
    sampler2D ambient;
    sampler2D height;
    //vec2 texCoord;            
};

struct Material {
    vec3 ambient;           // Ka
    vec3 diffuse;           // Kd
    vec3 specular;          // Ks
    vec3 transmittance;     // Tr
    vec3 emission;          // Ke
    float shininess;        // Ns
    float ior;              // Ni
    float dissolve;         // Dissolve
    int illum;              // Illum
    Texture texture;
};

uniform Material material;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;
```

Global Shader

```
    uniform mat4 VP;
uniform mat4 P;
```

What i am getting now after binding the buffers and running the directional shader is 
[image]

and just as example to see the scene this is the position buffer
[image]

Comment: ID: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Subroutine

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I had the clean buffer and color in the wrong place. It should be after I bind the buffer not at the beginning of each frame.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, deferredFbo);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    defferedShader_.startProgram();
    defferedShader_.setUniformMat4("VP", camera.getVP());
.
.
. rest of the code
```